# Why doesn't blur backdrop-filter work together with mask-image?

Tags: html, css

I have a container div with `mask-image` set and two children div with `backdrop-filter` set:

```html
<div class="scroll-view">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653744971341-ae4a77618399?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NTYzODM1OTM&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80");
}

.scroll-view {
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(transparent, black 20%, black 80%, transparent);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(transparent, black 20%, black 80%, transparent);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.inner {
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

On scrolling the children, I expect them to be fading out at the top and bottom edge of the container. Also, the background under the children area should be blurred.

But the blur filter doesn't get applied when `mask-image` is set. It only works when I comment out the `mask-image`, why?

Here's the codepen snippet: https://codepen.io/perqin/pen/rNdNBmy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backdrop filter doesn't seem to work if a parent is masked.
Below a workaround based on your demo.
Apply the same fixed background image on `<body>` and `<div class="inner">`

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653744971341-ae4a77618399?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NTYzODM1OTM&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80");
  background-attachment: fixed; /* make sure background is fixed */
}

.scroll-view {
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(transparent, black 20%, black 80%, transparent);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(transparent, black 20%, black 80%, transparent);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.inner {
  /*   backdrop-filter: blur(10px); disable backdrop filter */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.blur {
  /* new blur element inside .inner to create a fake backdrop blur effect */
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  position: relative;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  filter: blur(20px); /* set blur level */
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653744971341-ae4a77618399?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NTYzODM1OTM&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80"); /* apply same image as background */
  background-attachment: fixed; /* make sure background is fixed */
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-view">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="blur"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="blur"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```